# Deploying from Truffle to Infura.io

Tags: truffle, infura, truffle-migration

I'm trying to use the Infura or any other public provider to compile and migrate a simple test contract.

I don't get any errors when I run

```
truffle compile --network test
```

but it seems to hang and never complete

same with

```
truffle migrate --network live
```

here is a copy of my truffle.js (the mnemonic is made up in the below)

```
var bip39 = require("bip39");
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');
var ProviderEngine = require("web3-provider-engine");
var WalletSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/wallet.js');
var FiltersSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/filters.js');
var Web3Subprovider = require("web3-provider-engine/subproviders/web3.js");
var Web3 = require("web3");
var mnemonic = "know give beef link depth liberty fish forward ketchup fog either faculty";
var hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));
var wallet_hdpath = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/";
var wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(wallet_hdpath + "0").getWallet();
var address = "0x" + wallet.getAddress().toString("hex");
var provider_url = "https://testnet.infura.io/";
var engine = new ProviderEngine();
engine.addProvider(new WalletSubprovider(wallet, {}));
engine.addProvider(new FiltersSubprovider());
engine.addProvider(new Web3Subprovider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider_url)));
engine.start(); 

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    test: {
      network_id: 3,
      provider: engine,
      from: address
    }
  }
};
```

And my package.json is

```
    {
  "name": "Infura Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "truffle.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bip39": "^2.3.1",
    "ethereumjs-wallet": "^0.6.0",
    "truffle": "^3.4.5",
    "web3": "^0.18.2",
    "web3-provider-engine": "^13.2.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "@bkawk",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Did you end up solving your issue?

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/23320/15903) shows how to use the package `truffle-hdwallet-provider` and Infura:

In `truffle.js`:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var infura_apikey = "XXXXXX";
var mnemonic = "twelve words you can find in metamask/settings/reveal seed words blabla";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/"+infura_apikey),
      network_id: 3
    }
  }
};
```

Deploy on the ropsten network

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
// network connectivity error
engine.on('error', function(err) {
    // report connectivity errors
    console.error(err.stack)
})
```

before `engine.start();`

Answer (score 0):

> var provider_url = "https://testnet.infura.io/";

Try putting in your personal URL (that one with the key), e.g. "https://ropsten.infura.io/YourKeyThatWasSentToYourEmail"