# Steps to deploy a contract using MetaMask and Truffle

Tags: truffle, ropsten, truffle-contract, truffle-migration

i'm noob, I want to deploy my contract on Ropsten network with MetaMask & Truffle, plz explain to me the steps to deploy it.

Comment: Hi there. I think your question will be flagged as being too broad, I'm afraid. You could ask somewhere like Reddit, and then if you have specific problems, ask them here. www.reddit.com/r/ethereum

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Solution 1: With you own node**

You can easily deploy on the ropsten network if you own a full node running on your machine.

i. Run geth

```
$ geth --fast --cache=1048 --testnet --unlock "0xmyaddress" --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545
```

ii. In truffle.js, add the following configure for the ropsten network

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      host: "localhost", 
      port: 8546,
      network_id: "*" 
    },  
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "3"
    }
  }
};
```

iii. Deploy on the ropsten network

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

---

**Solution 2: With a public node like Infura**

i. Install the needed libraries

Navigate into the project folder and run the following command:

```
npm init

npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider --save
```

ii. In *truffle.js*, Add the following code to unlock your Metamask account and configure the Infura Ropsten node as entry point by providing the mnemonic phrase (Metamask / Settings / Reveal Seed Words)

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var infura_apikey = "XXXXXX";
var mnemonic = "twelve words you can find in metamask/settings/reveal seed words blabla";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/"+infura_apikey),
      network_id: 3
    }
  }
};
```

iii. Deploy on the ropsten network

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

---

EDIT: Replace the solution by `truffle-hdwallet-provider`.Way more simple solution than `ethereumjs-wallet bip39 web3-provider-engine web3`

Comment: Do i need download all blocks?

Comment: With the first solution, you need a local synchronised full node (all blocks). The second solution relies on a third party with a fully synchronised node, you don't need a node at all

Comment: i have error when i run second solution

Error: Cannot find module 'ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey'

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot one point in the second solution. You need to execute this command first: `npm install ethereumjs-wallet bip39 web3-provider-engine web3 --save` (I edited the answer with the details)

Comment: The problem was not resolved,Error: Cannot find module 'ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey'

Comment: I pushed my code on github to give you an example : https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/23279-what-is-steps-to-deploy-the-contract-on-ropsten-network

Comment: i have a lot missing packages like Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'.
can you add some information's to contact you by you'r profile account

Comment: Any reason this shouldn't work with `geth --light`?

Comment: For the second solution, I get `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The field nonce must not have more 32 bytes`. Using truffle-hdwallet-provider 0.0.5.

Comment: I'm so close but I am getting the error: Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
insufficient funds for gas * price + value. I am trying to push 1 billion tokens with the following gas
     ropsten:  {
     provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/MYAPIADDRESS"),
     network_id: 3,
     host: "127.0.0.1",
     port:  8545,
     gas:   2900000

How do I get the wallet address so I can fund it will ETH? or is the gas prices I have set wrong?