# deployment of a functioning contract (testrpc) to ropsten with truffle/geth

Tags: contract-deployment, ropsten, truffle-migration, testrpc-to-ropsten

I've developed a smart contract using truffle and testrpc, which can be found on [GitHub here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/solidificateur).

At this point I want to deploy it to `ropsten`, but I can't figure out how to do that.

After consulting [this question/answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/what-is-steps-to-deploy-the-contract-on-ropsten-network), I attempted to concoct a deployment for my smart contract as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      host: "localhost", 
      port: 8546, // for ropsten expose this one
      //port: 8545, // expose this one for testrpc
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },  
// for ropsten uncomment all of this
// for testrpc comment it all out
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "3"
    }
  }
};
```

and here's how I tried to execute the deployment:

```
> truffle migrate --network ropsten

Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
    Deploying Migrations...
    ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: exceeds block gas limit
```

This is a screenshot of the full terminal output:

[image]

My question is, how can I deploy [this simple contract](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/solidificateur/blob/master/contracts/Incrementer.sol) to `ropsten`?

---

**EDIT:**

Found this:

[image]

but it didn't seem to help, i.e. still getting an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the error message that you need to pay attention to is the:

```
Error: exceeds block gas limit
```

you can fix that by modifying you `truffle.js` to contain the line `gas: 500000` like so:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      host: "localhost", 
      port: 8546, // for ropsten expose this one
      //port: 8545, // expose this one for testrpc
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },  
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "3",
      gas: 500000
    }
  }
};
```

then deploy it like this:

```
truffle migrate --network ropsten --reset
```

and for me that seemed to work, as you can see here:

[image]