# Truffle deploy via Infura : does it work?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, infura

I've read mixed things.  In the docs for Truffle Framework there are instructions for deploying contracts via Infura's APIs.

But, elsewhere, I've read that Infura doesn't allow one to send transactions and hence deploying via Infura is not possible.

Which is it?

Has anyone managed to deploy via Infura?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, this answer provide a nice step by step guide how to use infura from truffle https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/23320.

Comment: Have you personally done this and gotten it to work?

I'm aware of that writeup and tried it.  It did not work.  My question here is for someone that's actually gotten the theoretical steps to actually work.  Infura does not support most RFC commands and as of a few months ago did not support this.

Comment: Yes, I've deployed successfully several contracts. If you have a particular problem ask a new question with your particular details so we can help you.

Comment: Just to confirm, you deployed via Infura?

Comment: Yes, make sure to set a correct gas price so it will be deployed quickly. If it is too low you transaction will be delayed and migrate will timeout. See here https://ethgasstation.info/ for the average pirice/wait.

Comment: @Ismael https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32770/error-linking-library-when-deploying-with-via-infura-ropsten  Here's the more specific question

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. From web3 docs:

> In order to transact with Infura nodes, you will need to create and
>   sign transactions offline before sending them, as Infura nodes have no
>   visibility of your encrypted Ethereum key files, which are required to
>   unlock accounts via the Personal Geth/Parity admin commands.

You will need to send sign transactions. Here is the relevant doc of web3:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction

Comment: So, you actually have done this yourself ?

Comment: And by "done this" I mean:  use `truffle migrate` to deploy contracts via Infura.