# Error linking library when deploying with via Infura (ropsten)

Tags: ropsten, ethereumjs, truffle-contract, truffle-migration, infura

I'm trying to deploy via Infura to ropsten and get this error.

The local deployment works without a hitch.

```
Linking SafeMath to contracts
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
undefined
truffle(ropsten)> Error: Cannot link library: SafeMath has no address. Has it been deployed?
```

The relevant lines from the deployment script are:

```
return deployer.deploy(SafeMath, {from: owner}).then(() => {
    console.log("Linking SafeMath to contracts");
    return deployer.link(SafeMath, [Cx1, Cx2]).then(() => {
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

Am running from within `truffle console --network ropsten`  with ropsten configured for Infura.  The migration of the migration contract seems to work fine.

I'm doing doing a `deploy`.

**It seems that unlike in local deployments, truffle is not updating the .json files.  Could this be the problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Had nothing to do with the above.

Was all about the account string being mixed case - which allows a kind of internal check-summing - and seems Truffle + Infura doesn't support this.