# Publicly accessible nodes for RPC

Tags: nodes, rpc

[It seems that truffle cannot deploy to a `--light` node](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/534).

I run a laptop where disk space is really tight.

Are there any publicly available testnet and mainnet nodes that I can interract with via RPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deploying your Smart Contract through Truffle via [Infura.io](https://infura.io/docs/#endpoints):

There are a few resources that can help you achieve this:

- [Truffle blog post on it](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider)
- [Related question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22911/deploying-from-truffle-to-infura-io)